# seekBar thumb gets stretched when seekBar is clicked

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm experiencing a strange issue. In my app I have a custom `SeekBar` with a thumb that has 2 states. When I click the `seekBar`, its thumb gets distorted and *returns to its normal condition after a couple of seconds.* The corresponding `MediaPlayer` object reacts immediately as expected, the issue is just a visual one. Snapshots to illustrate this:

Normal behavior:

[image]

When the `seekBar` is clicked:

[image]

I have no idea what is wrong about that.

SeekBar:

```
     <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:maxHeight="3dp"
        android:maxWidth="450dp"
        android:minHeight="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/pb"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_state" />
```

Drawable used for its Thumb:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb" android:state_pressed="false"/>

      </selector>
```

OnTouchListener:

```
        @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.seekBarMain) {

        if (mp.isPlaying()) {

            int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100)
                    * sb.getProgress();
            mp.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
        } else {
            int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100)
                    * sb.getProgress();
            mp.start();
            mp.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
            btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();

        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: I like the style. Do you mind sharing?

Comment: @SiKni8 sure. I have zipped the relevant resources, you can download them here (the link will be active for 5 days) http://files.mail.ru/38B5C7AFF63E4B9DBC942B43536AFE61   Let me know if I forgot something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright, I just figured out that the issue was somehow related to the `"thumb_pressed"` drawable which was about 25% larger then the drawable used for the normal state. I can't really explain that, but modifying the `"thumb_pressed"` drawable to have the same size as the `"thumb"` drawable fixed the issue.